# Deleting Children and Parents in MVC4 with EF Codefirst

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some parent/child relationships as follows:

```
public class Card
{
    public virtual int CardId { get; set; }
    public virtual Set ParentSet { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Side> Sides { get; set; }
}

public class Set
{
    public virtual int SetId { get; set; }
    public virtual Set ParentSet { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Card> Cards { get; set; }
}

public class Side
{
    public virtual int SideId { get; set; }
    public virtual Card ParentCard { get; set; }
}
```

So, a Set contains Cards which contain Sides.  A Set can also contain other Sets.

I tried creating a basic Delete controller action:

```
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int cardId)
{
    Card card = _db.Cards.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CardId == cardId);
    if (card == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    _db.Cards.Remove(card);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Detail", "Set", new {setId = card.ParentSet.SetId});
}
```

But I get an error DbUpdateException:

"An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types."

I can post the details here if needed, but I have a feeling this is an issue related to my models or config.  I would imagine that I don't have to build a cascading delete method for every entity that nulls out the parent FKs.... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see this error becouse You want to remove item with Forgein Key.

You should delete all Sides where Card==Deleting Card.

[Here You can find more information about deleting in EF](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/06/02/deleting-orphans-with-entity-framework/)